# Is it acceptable for a user to ask for a bounty on a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I recently found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33064329/2415822) bounty question.  In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064329/looking-for-alternative-solution-than-ipfw-for-slowing-down-an-internet-connecti#comment53960814_33064329), a user basically says that the question isn't worth answering to them without a bounty.

Is this acceptable behavior for StackOverflow?  In the spirit of helping people and answering questions, I'd say it is inappropriate to comment that a question isn't worth answering.  If it should be closed, flag it.  If it's a poor question, downvote it.  If it's not worth your time, ignore it.

EDIT: Screenshot for <10k users:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's nothing constructive about that comment, so flagging it as such would be fine.

So long as the user hasn't been causing a trend of comments like this, then I'd say that this is just a minor annoyance.  Flag it and move on.

Comment: The bounty has been up for a few days now but the guy is nowhere to be seen. So he wasn't even really asking for a bounty to answer the question - he's basically tricked the OP into "donating" their rep back to the community. Not so sure I'd call that a minor annoyance, considering once you put up a bounty you can't get it back under normal circumstances. I *could* take pity on the OP and reimburse them their rep in this specific situation, but we don't know if the bounty was indeed coerced. Meanwhile, *I* have something for the other user...

Comment: @BoltClock:  At this point it's kind of a double-edged sword, isn't it?  Yes, the 50 reputation was lost likely due to someone's flippant remark, but the question is getting attention as a result of it.   Is that a bad thing?  Also, would a bounty be refundable if it were the case that the user did it but then said that they made a mistake?  (There *are* a lot of warning signs before you agree to offer one...)

Comment: IMO there is a difference between making a mistake out of your own carelessness, and doing something out of coercion. But you have a point - the question is getting attention as a result of the bounty. Better than mine which received more views in its first couple of days than its entire 7-day bounty period.

Comment: @BoltClock It is possible that the user used one account to set it up, and another account to answer it and get the points.

Answer (score 15):

No.

StackOverflow has always been a site intended to be a collection of knowledge, where people can ask questions that are of use to a wide audience, and others who can help share their knowledge to provide information to others can answer those questions. Asking for *payment* in any form to provide that information is totally against the intent of SO (and all of the other StackExchange sites), and any comment that asks for payment in any form should be flagged as "not constructive", and any answer that suggests that a bounty would provide a better solution should be downvoted.

If someone wants to participate here, their goal should be to share knowledge they have with others who have a problem you can help them solve. If your goal is simply to increase your own implied sense of worth with meaningless internet points, you're in the wrong place. If you want to *charge* people for sharing your knowledge, visit a site where people seek *consultants* or *contractors* for hire; this is not the site for you.

Comment: Advising about the existence of bounties is not bad though; this was just worded as poor as you can make it.

Comment: "rep." != "payment". Our "rep." points are not exchangeable for goods or services. At most, they unlock parts of the web site; not much different from similar mechanisms in video games...I don't see anyone confusing those mechanisms with paying the player for playing the game. There is also the question of how you define "asking". I would agree that requests of the form "give me X" are bad form, but providing suggestions to new users as to how they could receive more/better help, or even that they should vote/accept answers seems reasonable, and yet could be construed as "asking for payment"

Comment: @Peter: It is asking for remuneration for answering the question. "I'll answer you if you compensate me with reputation for doing so" is a clear request for remuneration, and it's in direct opposition to the basics of these sites. The comment (which has been deleted, so no one can see it now) didn't say "You should add a bounty to try and get help"; it said "I can answer if you give me a bounty". That's clearly asking for payment.

Comment: @PeterDuniho consider that one's StackOverflow rep might be looked at by potential employers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho to follow up Peters remark, reputation still had a tangible benefit outside the site as it is an indication of your expertise in a field. Putting that you're a high rep user on SO on your resume isn't something to snub.

Comment: @KenWhite So you're saying that you don't have a problem with someone being reimbursed for answering an SO question, you just have a problem with someone asking to be reimbursed for answering an SO question?  If so, then it seems you have a problem with bounties (and even rep) in general.  Personally I'd say that it's in bad taste, and certainly reflects poorly on them, but that's true of all sorts of actions/comments, and isn't strictly against the rules.  At most you can say that it's just noise, as the other answer states, as it isn't adding anything productive to the post.

Comment: @Servy: No, I have no problem with users voluntarily offering a bounty to direct attention to their question, and I have no problem with someone receiving a bounty that was voluntarily offered. I have a problem with users who ransom their answers by demanding a bounty be offered in order to receive their help, just like I would have a problem with a police officer demanding that I pay them for offering assistance when I was being assaulted, or an EMT demanding cash before rendering assistance to my injured family member. Coercion is inappropriate, particularly here.

Comment: (continued). Actually, I'm somewhat surprised by your comment. From previous remarks you've made (both here and at the main Meta), I know you understand the basic premise of these sites, which is to create a knowledge base of *shared* knowledge. Sharing does not mean *offered by coercing something*; sharing means *freely imparted* here. I strongly feel it's inappropriate here to see a user struggling with a problem and not receiving help, realize you have the ability to help them by sharing your knowledge, and then deciding *but only if I receive special compensation first*.

Comment: And I never said it was *against the rules*. I said it was *inappropriate*.

Comment: @KenWhite Your analogies are completely inappropriate.  It's an *obligation* of police to assist you if you're being assulted, or for an EMT to help you if you're injured.  They're of course *already being paid* to do that work.  SO users are volunteers who are under no obligation to do anything.  A more applicable analogy is a street performer who only actually plays a song when they are paid, rather than one that plays for free but with a tip jar.  You might prefer the latter, but the person is entirely within their rights to do the former, even if you think that it's tacky.

Comment: @KenWhite I said I would consider such a comment distasteful, and I certainly would have very little respect for such a person, but that doesn't make such a comment inappropriate or meriting deletion on the grounds that I think that it's contrary to the site's goals.  And note that your question opens by saying "no" to the OP's question of whether or not it's acceptable to post such a comment, so you *did* say that it's unacceptable for such a comment to be posted, which is different than just being distasteful or rude.  To me the same as people asking others to upvote/accept their answers.

Comment: @Servy: You're right about my previous analogies being incorrect. A more appropriate one would be a volunteer in a soup kitchen agreeing to serve a meal to a homeless person only if they paid them something first. If they're here to volunteer, they should do just that-volunteer-rather than attempt co coerce payment for performing the service they're here to *volunteer*. It's pointless to offer to *volunteer* when you're going to demand compensation first for doing so. It violates the *spirit* of SE, even if it doesn't violate the stated guidelines. And yes, I said *inappropriate*. It is, IMO.

Comment: @KenWhite You do realize that there are soup kitchens that do actually have paid employees.  Not every person working at every soup kitchen is a volunteer.  By the same token, not everyone answering questions on SO is a volunteer; there are plenty of people answering questions because they want something in return for those answers.  While having people volunteer is nice, sometimes you just can't get valuable services for free.  This applies to most everything in this world, including SO.  It's tacky.  You can find it distasteful, as I do, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: @Servy: Wait. *You're* the one that said *SO users are volunteers*, and now you're switching to *not everyone answering questions on SO is a volunteer*. Which is it? You're sounding like a politician, talking out of both sides of your mouth. Unless the person answering the question is a paid SE employee, they are a volunteer. While a reasonable expectation might be to receive an upvote or an accept for providing an answer, expecting payment **before** doing so is inappropriate. Your remark about paid employees in the soup kitchen is irrelevant, as I specifically mentioned a *volunteer* worker.

Comment: @Servy: And even in the case of those paid workers in the soup kitchen, it would still be inappropriate for them to demand payment from that homeless person before serving them their meal.

Comment: The key point of my earlier comment is that SO users aren't *obligated* to post answers.  *SE* doesn't pay people to answer posts, and people posting questions (generally) aren't paying answerers, but it's not unheard of for companies to pay people to answer SO questions, and plenty of people answer SO questions for what they get in return *even if those things aren't money*, such as the experience, reputation (not just SE reputation, but also in the sense of something to put on a resume), etc.  The user wasn't asking to be paid first; a bounty couldn't be awarded before he posts an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite "I specifically mentioned a volunteer worker" so then, to follow the analogy, this is someone going to a soup kitchen and applying for a paid position, saying that a volunteer position isn't worth his time. "[...] demand payment from that homeless person before serving them their meal" this is again a point where the analogy breaks down.  I much prefer my earlier analogy of a street performer.  In most situations its expected that they're playing for tips, not to be paid; if one only played after being tipped it'd be tacky, but if they're really that good, you may find it worth it.

Comment: @Servy: OK. I guess we agree to disagree. The question asked here was whether the conduct was appropriate, and in my opinion (and as I answered) it is not. If someone is here because their job compensates them for it, then they're already being paid. If they're here for the rep, they're here for the wrong reasons *in the spirit of the stated goals of SO*.I'd be embarrassed to use my SO rep as a resume point and then have a potential employer find a post where I said *I can help you, and will do so only if you offer a bounty first*, and I'd certainly hold that against someone applying for a job

Comment: @KenWhite If posting questions to earn rep is against the spirit of SO, then *why does SO have rep in the first place*?  Rep *exists* because it's an incentive for people to contribute content.  It's a part of the gamification of the site, which SE has talked about quite a lot as a key aspect of the site, and is something that they actively work to encourage.  Personally I find that it's one of the areas where my views deviate from SE's mission a bit, as I feel that they often go too far down the gamification route, and that can cause some nasty side effects.

Comment: @Servy: Damn, you find the most interesting ways to (wrongly) twist what I say. I never once said earning rep is against the spirit of SO. I said that **demanding the rep from a user before helping** is inappropriate. Earning rep is just that-doing the work and (possibly) being rewarded for doing so afterward. Coercing someone before offering the help is what I'm objecting to, and I find it difficult to see why you can't comprehend the difference between those two things. You think gamification is the wrong path, and yet you encourage coercion in order to increase the *game points*?

Comment: FWIW, the Supreme Court [ruled](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/06/28/politics/justices-rule-police-do-not-have-a-constitutional-duty-to-protect-someone.html?_r=0) that police officers are not obligated to protect you. Not really relevant to the topic at hand, but not common knowledge.

Comment: You specifically stated "If they're here for the rep, they're here for the wrong reasons in the spirit of the stated goals of SO."  That was what I was responding to.  I would also say that classifying this case as "coercion" is completely off base.  Asking for payment for a service isn't coercion.  If a mod threatened to delete all answers posted to the question unless the user posted a bounty *that* would be coercion.  I also didn't in any way encourage asking for a bounty before answering.  I said that it's tacky and rude, *but no more than that*.  The moral indignation is just not merited.

Comment: @Chris: It is in fact irrelevant to the discussion (we've agreed my analogy was inappropriate), but the link you post does not say they have no obligation; it says they  do not have a *constitutional duty* to do so. There's a difference. The constitution may not require them to protect you, but the terms of their employment certainly do.

Comment: @Servy: OK..We're at the point of your telling me what my moral point of view should be. I think we're done here. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Perhaps "coercion" was too strong a word, but the point remains that someone was being pressured into doing something they were under absolutely no obligation to do, for totally unjustifiable reasons. (Not pinging because I have no interest in discussing this further, just wanted to acknowledge said word choice.)